# Asynchronous helper library for C++

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I was programming node.js in the last days and heavily used the async [library](https://github.com/caolan/async). It is a library which introduces functions which handle common workflows in asynchronous programming. There are functions which run asynchronous calls in parallel or after another and call a single callback after all functions are finished (or an error occured).

Are there any librarys like this for C++?

I really like asynchronous programming, but the huge amount of callbacks (all of them with error handling etc) are really hard to read and maintain and are kind of ugly. I would love to continue coding in the way I experienced with the async library.

I guess that such a library is harder to realize in a language with less dynamic typing like C++.

PS: Suggestions how to make async code prettier are also welcome.

edit: I am using g++ with C++11.

edit 2: "Asynchronous" means working with non-blocking functions with callbacks in this context, not running parallel threads in the background. An example is boost:asio.

edit 3: I am already using boost::asio and would like to enhance the readibility of the code (clarity of the control flow, ...) with such a library.

Comment: *"Asynchronous" means ...* **NO** see tag "asynchronous" (the one you've used): *Asynchronous programming is simply allowing some portions of code to be executed on separate threads. It makes your applications perform better, be more responsive, and use the resources of the system they are running on to the fullest extent.*

Comment: Most of what you feel you're missing really isn't so much the async library, but node itself. It's got an event loop under the covers, which calls your functions (in a single thread) whenever it "makes sense", and all I/O calls are non-blocking. You can do the same thing in C++, but you've got to build it yourself, or use a library like `boost::asio` or ACE. Once you've got that, adding things like `forEach` or `waterfall` is the easy part. (And most C++ libraries that provide things that sound similar are going to be focused on thread parallelism, not node-style event-loop async.)

Comment: One big question: Why do you have to do this (whatever this is) in C++ instead of node.js in the first place?

Comment: @abarnert: I am using C++ because the code has to run on a 200 Mhz ARM device without hardware floating point support.

Comment: Good answer… but that may restrict a lot of other things. For example, many C++ async I/O libraries are designed for "server platforms", which means they're only optimized for, tested on, or even ported to—x86/x64 linux/BSD/Mac/Windows. Are you at least running linux (or iOS), or is this some horrible embedded platform?

Comment: @abarnert: I am using Linux. Boosts asio is running fine so far and even Qt is running quite smooth.

Comment: That's good news. I wonder if a node.js interpreter modified to store numbers as, say, a fixed-point pair of integers instead of a double would be (a) easy enough to hack up, and (b) useful enough to use, as long as you remembered that it wasn't quite standard JS… But that's probably way out of scope for your project anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you must already know, given that you're using it, boost.asio gets you part of the way there. But it's not going to be the same. Let me explain why.

Both node and asio are designed around the idea of a proactor. If you want to do something blocking (or just slow), you submit the job to the proactor, and it runs whenever it's appropriate and then calls your callback when it's finished.

But in node, *everything* goes through the proactor; there are no other kinds of async APIs. If you want to talk to a MySQL database, the interface takes a SQL statement and calls you back with a rowset. In C++, the interface takes a SQL statement and either blocks before giving you a cursor, or gives you an object that you can poll or block on. For files and sockets, you can ignore all the other APIs like `select` or `aio_read` because asio has complete wrappers, but for almost anything else, you have to do the work to write a wrapper, and often it's a lot of work.

More seriously, the standard callback interface in node is `callback(error, result)`, where the `result` is a JS object, which can have any members that are appropriate. The standard callback interface in asio is `void callback(const error_code&)`, where there *is* no result. You bind a mutable object into the task. This would already make it more clumsy to do control flow, because there's no way an object can follow another without knowing how its predecessor stashed its mutable data. This also mean that you need shared mutable data (which, unlike node, may be shared across threads), whether you want it or not. But of course the biggest problem is that the data is statically typed. (Often people build C++ classes, and share state by having the tasks be bound methods of the same object, but that isn't actually required.)

Of course you can write code to do fully dynamic objects in C++ (or maybe just one level of dynamicness, like a `vector<boost::any>` is sufficient), but it's still going to be clumsier to use than in JS, and you'll be giving up much of the performance benefit you were hoping to get by moving to C++.

So, it would be pretty easy to write functions like `void async::waterfall(vector<void(const error_code&)>> tasks)` that did exactly the same thing as `async.waterfall(tasks)`, but it wouldn't get you all the same benefits you're looking for.

Another point to consider is that you've switched to C++ for a reason: You're on a slow, resource-constrained system. Using a proactor to achieve data parallelism, equivalent to `async.forEach`, isn't unworkable, but it's not going to be as efficient as a plain old thread pool and a parallel-for library that knows how to use it.

Answer (score 3):

simply use C++. `std::async` does the job. no need for other than the standard C++ library (requires C++11, is implemented in several compilers already)

Comment: That is not what I mean with "asynchronous". Clarified in edit 2.

Comment: @thammi: Whether or not the execution of `std::asyc` actually takes place in a separate thread is implementation-defined, as far as I can tell. It's definitely asynchronous, though.

Comment: @Walter: I am sorry, I did not realize there was a clarification to the tags. I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

When talking about async and C++, [asio](http://think-async.com/) comes to my mind. This library is focused on asynchronous I/O, but also allows to write custom "services" to be used with the framework (as e.g. shown in [this example](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.5.3/doc/asio/examples.html#asio.examples.services)).

Answer (score 1):

While personally I would go with Walter's recommendation of C++11's standard library, I'd also like to point to

[Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html)

for completeness.